# Angular changeDetectorRef.detectChanges() is making the page jump/scroll to the top

Tags: html, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a function that takes in a list of objects that are used to for display in the view. It looks like this:

```
  myFunction(objects: myObjects[]){
    this.objects = objects;
    this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
  }
```

This function is called in a subscription callback. eg:

```
this.myService.ReplaySubject.subscribe(_ => this.myFunction(_));
```

And the value of the replay subject is set on a polling interval in the service, so the data can be refreshed automatically and consumed in other components.

In the template I have a loop for the items in the list… eg:

```
<div class=“wrapper” *ngFor=“let object of this.objects; let i=index”>
```

The content is changing as expected, but the issue is that the page is scrolling/jumping to the top of the page each time I call `changeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` in `myFunction()`. I have tried calling `changeDetectorRef.detach()` in my component constructor and the method itself to see if that would maintain the scroll position, but I had no luck. I am sort of stumped for what else to try. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to add a track by function in your for loop. Without it, each time the items are generated, the *ngFor is recalled and every child is generated again.

Comment: I have been working with angular for months and still did not know about this feature. THANK YOU!!! you just pulled  me out of hours of frustration.